# SSJS Create Data Extension with Retention

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I'm using following SSJS script to create a Data Extension and set the retention of 7 days at row level:

```
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");
var deObj = {
    "CustomerKey": "my_DE",
    "Name": "my DE",
    "DataRetentionPeriodLength": 7,
    "DataRetentionPeriod": "Days",
    "DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod": true,
    "RowBasedRetention": false,
    "ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport": false,
    "Fields": [{
            "Name": "id",
            "FieldType": "Text",
            "MaxLength": 100,
            "IsPrimaryKey": true,
            "IsRequired": true
        },
        {
            "Name": "person_id",
            "FieldType": "Text",
            "MaxLength": 80
        }
    ]
};
try {

    var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);

} catch (ex) {
    Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
}
```

I could not find any documentation around the Retention attributes but I took the SOAP envelope attributes and tried using it in SSJS. But I keep getting error. Are the `DataRetentionPeriodLength` , `DataRetentionPeriod` , `DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod` , `RowBasedRetention` , `ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport`  not supported with SSJS `DataExtension.Add` function?

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: I believe the issue could be permission based. Make sure you have the Administrative Data Management role set.

Comment: You are right! I added the role and it worked! the SSJS script does not work from Cloud Pages but worked when run through the Automation

Answer (score 2):

As [@Gortonington](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12730/gortonington) mentioned above `DataExtension.Add` works of you give `Data Manager` role. But as we found out from one of our Salesforce Consultant WSProxy works without this role as well. The code he shared was as below:

```
    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var name = "Retention_Testing";

    var de = {
        Name: name,
        CustomerKey: name,
        Description: "Retention_Testing",
        Fields: [{
            FieldType: "Text",
            Name: "Field1",
            MaxLength: 254,
            IsPrimaryKey: true,
            IsNillable: false,
            IsRequired: true
    },
    {
        FieldType: "Text",
        Name: "Field2",
        MaxLength: 254
    }],
    DataRetentionPeriodLength: 7,
    DataRetentionPeriod: "Days",
    RowBasedRetention: 0,
    ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport: 1,
    DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod: 0
}

  var res = prox.createItem("DataExtension", de);
```

Comment: As a note, I tried this while logged into a user without the data admin manager permission and it threw an error saying I needed that permission enabled to set retention on DEs.